# Elementary C++ Type Confusion

Tags: c++, types, constructor

I was reading [the following text from Stanford's Programming Paradigms class](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs107l/handouts/02-Copy-Constructors.pdf), and I noticed that when the author uses the string class, the constructor does a function call that looks like this:

```
string::string(const char* str) {
    initializeFrom(str, str + strlen(str));
}
```

If the initializeFrom function takes two char* arguments, how come the second argument can pass a (char* + int) to a char* and have it work out properly? How does the type system interpret this statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strlen()` actually returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. One of the important differences is that `size_t` is an unsigned type, i.e. it can only hold positive numbers. This makes sense - string lengths can be 0, 1, or 30000 characters, but never -7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is called pointer arithmetic.  A char* + int results in a char* that is int characters higher in memory.

Comment: If the `int` is -ve it could be lower in memory as well; so it should be an `unsigned int` for the result to be *always* higher in memory. [Sorry if this is nitpicking ;]

Comment: @legends2k That is true, although strlen() should never return a negative value, so the particular code under analysis here will result in the second argument always being greater than or equal to the first.

Comment: `strlen()` **will** never return a negative number. It simply can't; it returns a size_t, and that is an unsigned type.

Answer (score 3):

Binary additive operators `+` and `-` can be used when one argument is a pointer to any complete type (say, `T* p`) and the other argument is an integer (say, `i`). They implement so called *pointer arithmetic*.

The compiler assumes that the pointer is pointing to an element of some array (say, `T array[N]`). The operation produces a pointer to another element of the array, which is `i` elements away from the original element. It is possible to "move" the pointer in either direction, i.e. towards the beginning of the array or towards the end of the array. For example, if `p` points to `array[3]`, then `p + 4` will point to `array[7]`.

The operation is only valid when the result points to an existing element of the array or one past the last element of the array, i.e. given the array `T array[N]`, it is possible to create pointers to elements from `array[0]` to the imaginary element `array[N]`. Any attempts to cross these bounds using pointer arithmetic result in undefined behavior.

The type `T` has to be complete, meaning that pointer arithmetic cannot be used with `void *` pointers, for one example, even though some compilers allow this as an extension (treating `void *` pointers as equivalent to `char *` pointers).

In addition to the binary additive operators, pointer arithmetic also includes prefix and postfix unary `++` and `--` operators (applied to pointers) as well as compound assignment operators `+=` and `-=` (with pointers on their left-hand side and integers on the right-hand side).

In your case, `str + strlen(str)` expression will produce a pointer of `char *` type that points to the terminating `\0` character in the string `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a pointer is just a variable that holds a memory address.  So you can add values to a memory address.  A memory address is a number.

When you add 1 to a pointer of a certain type, it will actually add 1 * sizeof(type).  When you add any value N, it will actually add N * sizeof(type).

Consider the following example:

```
int x[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int *p = &(x[0]);//point to the first element
p = p + 1;//p now points to the second element.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument points to the start of the char array and the second points the NULL char at the end of the char array.

```
const char *str = "abc";
char *start = str; // start now points to the first char.
char *end = str + strlen(str); // end now points to the null char at the end.
```

You can confirm this by printing:

```
printf("%c %d",*start,*end); // will output: a 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> how come the second argument can pass a (char* + int)

It is still passing a `char *` pointing to `strlen(str)` past the initially pointed location.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be over-answered.

In:

```
 initializeFrom(str, str + strlen(str));
```

`str` is a pointer to the start of the string.

`(str + strlen(str))` is a pointer to the end of the string.

Keep in mind that `str` (a character pointer) is just an integer (`(int)`, `(long)`, `(long long)` depending on architecture) that identifies a location in memory.

Comment: A pointer is not (always) an integer. On x86-16 for instance,  it's a pair of integers.